# Determine if it is possible to make subsets of tuples depending upon max and min elements in the tuple

Tags: algorithm, tuples, grouping, dynamic-programming

We need to form subset of the given set to match the criteria.

Each tuple has 2 values. Min and Max elements in the group.

Each tuple needs to be in a group of size 1 or more.

If a tuple has values (2, 4):

- Then it can be placed in a group of 2 or 3 or 4.

If a tuple has values (3, 3):

- Then it can be placed only in a group of 3.

So is there an algorithm which can determine if we can form groups based on the criteria.

Eg:
n = 5, (x[], y[]) = { (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3) }.

The groups can be formed as:

- Group 1: { (1,2), (2,2) }
- Group 2: { (1,3), (2,3), (3,3) }
  return Possible

Eg:
n=5, (x[], y[]) = { (1,2), (1,2), (2,3), (2,2), (3,3) }

It is impossible to make subsets as there is one other tuple (2,3) to match with our (3,3) tuple, but we are short of 1 more tuple.
And (3,3) needs exactly 3 tuples in its group.
return Impossible

Comment: *"no other tuple having max elements as 3"* What about `(2,3)`?

Comment: Yes, that can be clubbed in but (3,3) needs exactly 3 elements in the subset. And we are short of 1 more.
I ll change the wording.

Comment: That would place the possible groups together, how do I determine where to split it into groups/subset ?

Answer (score 0):

create from each tuple a list of all its possible values, (2,4)->(2,3,4)
create all possible combination that you take one number from each list
check if in any of the combination each num appear num times (3 appears 3 times, 2 appears 2 times...)
this means there is a combination where each tuple is in a group valid for him

not completely sure it works

```
b = []
for t in my_set:
    b.append(list(range(t[0],t[1]+1)) #from each tuple create a list of its range,(1,3)->(1,2,3)

import itertools as it
all_pr = list(it.product(*b)) #create all possible combination where taking one from each list

from collections import Counter
for pr in all_pr:
    count = Counter(pr) #create a dict that counts how many times a value appears in a list
    valid = True
    for k in count:
        if count[k]%k != 0:
            valid = False
            break
    if valid == True:
        print("valid set", pr)
        break
```